# LeftBarButtonItem and RightBarButtonItem not shown in MonoTouch.Dialog DialogViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

MonoTouch is 5.2.12. iOS is v5.1.1 (Simulator)

Seems like I'm missing an important piece of a puzzle here.
I'm subclassing `DialogViewController` and set it as the only controller in my UINavigationController.
In `ViewWillAppear` of the subclassed `DialogViewController`, I'm trying to set the left and right bar button items:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, this.HandleDoneButtonTouched );
```

Neither one of them is showing up. The title however is displayed. If I debug, I can see that the items are properly set.

I have also tried to use `SetItems()` on the navigation controller: no effects either.

The navigation controller is presented modally in a page sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigation items are not usually updated through the navigation controller.  Instead, they are updated via the NavigationItem property on the view controller:

```
this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromFile("some_image.png")
        , UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
        , (sender,args) => {
           // button was clicked
        })
    , true);
```

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/Content_Controls/Navigation_Controller/Add_a_Nav_Bar_Right_Button